# qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer - SSL certificate problem & Raster layer Provider is not valid

Tags: qgis, gdal, ssl

I am trying to add an ArcGIS Server Image Service located here:
https://orthos.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/T2011Resolution_Test/ImageServer

In the python editor in QGIS (64 bit 3.2.0), when I try this code snippet:

qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("https://orthos.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/T2011Resolution_Test/ImageServer?f=json&pretty=true","raster")

I am getting these errors:

2018-07-18T10:22:57     CRITICAL    Invalid Layer : GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset https://orthos.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/T2011Resolution_Test/ImageServer?f=json&pretty=true:
             SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
             Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: https://orthos.its.ny.gov/arcgis/rest/services/T2011Resolution_Test/ImageServer?f=json&pretty=true

Now, I know that GDAL has a file type, but no idea how to update it. Also, the machine that I am calling the url on has the certificate loaded, so I'm confused as to why, the Python editor in QGIS is throwing a SSL certificate problem.

Also if I try map services over https I get the same errors mentioned above.

Note that this code works fine:

qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/ESRI_Imagery_World_2D/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true","raster")

But the above is over http, and from what I can tell ESRI_Imagery_World is added into GDAL. If I change it to https then I get the same errors mentioned above.

I'm surprised at this point that we can't just send things over https. Most interfaces aren't http capable these days or there is a redirect to https. In the case where I am getting the error, there is a redirect to https so if I change to http, I am still getting the error.

Any ideas would be helpful. I searched this forum and have searched online, but most developers are not trying to load Image Services, but Map services. And there is a difference.